# How to keep non-current versions in a nested folder via Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, s3-lifecycle-policy

I have a bucket with a structure like this:

- root

  - source
  - processed

    - form

I would like non-current versions to expire in everything except the form directory.

Will this work, or do I need to create individual rules for source, processed, and forms?

```
            "LifecycleConfiguration": {
                "Rules" : [{
                    "NoncurrentVersionExpiration" : {
                        "NoncurrentDays": 1
                    },
                    "Status": "Enabled"
                }, {
                    "Prefix": "form",
                    "NoncurrentVersionExpiration" : {
                        "NoncurrentDays": 1
                    },
                    "Status": "Disabled"
                }]
            },
```

Comment: "Will this work," - why not run it and check it?

Comment: Let us know how it goes, if it doesn't work I'd check the prefix could be `processed\form`